# overriding UIView:initWithFrame and got nil parameters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

I have a class that extend from UIView. I used that for creating custom default view. I use the `-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;` but when i used the initializer, the `frame` parameter is always `null` value.

Here is the code:

```
#import "SomeView.h"
@implementation POIView
@synthesize theButton;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    NSLog(@"%@",frame);
  }
  return self;
}
@end
```

The NSLog result is always `(null)`, and this is where i called the initialization

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CELL_ID";
 const int THE_TAG         = 1000;

 UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) {
   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
   CGRect *rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width,tableView.rowHeight);
   someView = [[SomeView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
 }else{
   someView = (SomeView *) [cell viewWithTag:THE_TAG];
 }
 return cell;
}
```

I used it now on the tableView, but i used the someview to some UILabel too.

Comment: Please show us the code where you call `initWithFrame:`.

Comment: done, i've add the source where i call the `initWithFrame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

frame is a struct, it is not a sub-class from NSObject. You can show the frame value by following way.

```
NSLog(@"%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f",frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
```

**NSLog(@"%@", aObj);** is equal to **NSLog(@"%@",[aObj description]);**

Comment: It's far easier to show the value using `NSStringFromCGRect()`. That would however not solve this problem, since frame is still `null`.

Comment: Apparently this is the problem, after i changed it into NSLog(@"%f",frame.size.width). The parameter wasn't `null` after all. Thanks

Comment: @klaaspieter: you are right. NSStringFromCGRect() is easier. But the core problem is that CGRect come from typedef struct { ... }. It is not a sub-class of NSObject. So, it has no -(NSString *)description method. Because it is not an instance of NSObject.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that CGRectMake has return type CGRect and not CGRect *. Thus the line:

```
CGRect *rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width,tableView.rowHeight);
```

should be

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width,tableView.rowHeight);
```